# How to send parameters of type string array [String] and string (multiple types) in Alamofire multipart upload?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm currently doing a network call using alamofire multipart upload where i'm sending image data and parameters which is key, value pair. However, the value can me of type String or [String]. It is working if all params are String but crashes when parameter key is of type [String]. Here is my code:

```
func childSignUpWithParameters(data:Data?,_ parameters: Parameters,
                             completion: @escaping (Bool, User?, Any?)->Void) {
  let accessToken = "JWT" + " " + (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.kAuthToken.rawValue) as! String)
  let headers_ =
    ["Authorization": accessToken]
  let url = BaseUrl + APIPathGenerator.addChild.rawValue
  Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (mpData) in
//to add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
      mpData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
    }

//to add image data:
    if let image = data {
      mpData.append(image,
                    withName: "image",
                    fileName: "file.jpeg",
                    mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }
  }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
     to: url,
     method: .post, headers: headers_, encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) in
      switch encodingResult {
      case .success(let upload, _, _):
```

So the problem is in the line:

```
   mpData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
```

For array of string we cannot force cast it to String. Also if I dont force cast it I get error that value of type Any has no member data. And without .data I get error in .utf8 .

Comment: what is the type of `Parameters` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
mpData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
```

by using `(value as! String)` you are telling the compiler that you are 100% sure that `value` is a `String`. This is obviously not the case, since you say it can be `[String]` as well. You will have to encode that array to a `Data` object somehow. Now it is hard to suggest anything to you, because the correct solution depends on how the server expects the data to be encoded. But maybe I am able to point you to right direction.

E.g., let us consider this array of strings:

```
let array = ["a", "b"]
```

If it should be sent as:

```
["a", "b"]
```

You can simply use:

```
mpData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
```

However, if you need to encode it let's say as:

```
a, b
```

Then you will have to do some encoding yourself:

```
if let stringValue = value as? String {
    mpData.append(stringValue.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
} else if let arrayString = value as? [String] {
    let stringValue = arrayString.joined(separator: ", ")
    mpData.append(stringValue.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
}
```

Comment: mpData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)  did it, 
thanks for the encoding explaination

Comment: @RomitKumar  - what the  different you get from my answer and this answer

Comment: here placing if else leading repeated code, after all its resolved using `"\(value)"`.

Comment: @vaibhav there is repeated code, but not without a reason - this explicitly deals with different input types in case simple "\(value)" encoding is not enough

Answer (score 1):

Change type of your parameter to `parameters: [String : Any]` and append your values like:

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
    mpData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
}
```

Calling:

```
self.childSignUpWithParameters(data: /*yourData*/, parameters: self.getParameters(), ...

func getParameters() -> [String: Any]{
    let params = ["key2": "value1",
                  "key1": "value2"
    return params
}
```

Using `Any` you dont need to bothered about specific type, whatever the value you send it will successfully to the server using cast `\(value)"` in loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code..**

```
func CompleteShipmentAPI(){

        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(signatureImageView.image!, 0.25)!

        let ShipID:NSNumber =  mdicShipmentDetails.value(forKey: "id") as! NSNumber

        // userDetails
        let paramerers:Parameters = ["ship_id":ShipID.stringValue]

        print(paramerers)

        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "x-api-key": AUTH_API_KEY
        ]
        let isImageOnProducts:NSNumber = mdicShipmentDetails.value(forKey: "isImageOnProducts") as! NSNumber
        let isDigitalSignature:NSNumber = mdicShipmentDetails.value(forKey: "isDigitalSignature") as! NSNumber

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if isImageOnProducts.stringValue == "1"{
                //SHOW
                 multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "product_img",fileName: "product.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
            if isDigitalSignature.stringValue == "1"{
                //SHOW
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "shipment_sign",fileName: "signature.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }

            for (key, value) in paramerers {
                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key )
            }
        },to:BASE_URL+kPOST_COMPLETE_API, headers:headers){ (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseString { response in

                    MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

                    if let strResponse:String  = response.result.value  {
                        print(strResponse)



                    }

                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```